# Expansion of laravel Route::resource laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

For middleware reasons I decided to expand my current `Route::resource` routes on Laravel 7. However, I do want to make sure routes are expanded properly and identically so there are no issues in future. I came up with this list of routes :

```
Route::get('checklists', 'ChecklistController@index')->name('checklists.index');

Route::get('checklists/create', 'ChecklistController@create')->name('checklists.create');

Route::post('checklists', 'ChecklistController@store')->name('checklists.store');

Route::get('checklists/{checklist}', 'ChecklistController@show')->name('checklists.show');

Route::get('checklists/{checklist}/edit', 'ChecklistController@edit')->name('checklists.edit');

Route::match(['PUT', 'PATCH'], 'checklists/{checklist}', ['as' => 'checklists.update', 'uses' => 'ChecklistController@update']);

Route::delete('checklists/{checklist}', 'ChecklistController@destroy')->name('checklists.destroy');
```

instead of:

```
Route::resource('checklists', 'ChecklistController');
```

It may be a bit weird question, but could anyone confirm if this expanded version would generate an exact replacement for `Route::resource`? And if not, what else do I need to do to make sure it works exactly same? I could not find that information.

Comment: You can verify this yourself. Define the resource route and do ```php artisan route:list```.

Comment: @KurtFriars thanks, I forgot that option!

Comment: I checked and found all same. you can check this link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an exact answer to your question, however I think your code would be a lot cleaner if you just used what is needed and appended the remainder

```
Route::resource('checklists', 'ChecklistController')->except('update');
Route::match(['PUT', 'PATCH'], 'checklists/{checklist}', ['as' => 'checklists.update', 'uses' => 'ChecklistController@update']);
```